# DPI виртуализация

Tags: windows, масштабирование, dpi

Что конкретно обозначается под DPI, когда речь идёт о масштабировании интерфейса? Простое определение: dpi - это количество точек на дюйм бумаги при печати. Не совсем ясна суть, когда речь идёт о методе виртуализации DPI в Windows. Чем больше это значение указываешь в настройках, тем крупнее становится изображение. Но в чём логика, если точек на дюйм становится больше, а изображение не становится от этого меньше - всё наоборот.

Возьмём для примера отрисовку линии длиной 96 пикселей. DPI системы равен 120, PPI - 144. Какова будет длина линии в дюймах? Ответ: 5/6 дюйма. Но как это работает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DPI в Windows - это число пикселей на логический дюйм, а не физический. Нет смысла на его основе пытаться вычислить "размер чего-то в дюймах", так как эта настройка на самом деле предназначена для обратного, вычисления "размера чего-то в пикселях".

Логический дюйм задается как высота строки 72-го шрифта. Тогда высота строки N-го шрифта в пикселях определяется формулой:

```
DPI * N / 72
```

Отсюда и происходит увеличение размеров.

Разумеется, шрифт здесь только для примера. Масштабирование DWM затрагивает не только шрифты, все линейные размеры элементов UI увеличиваются на фиксированный масштабный коэффициент, равный DPI / 96.

Подробная информация: [DPI and Device-Independent Pixels](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/dpi-and-device-independent-pixels)

Comment: Иными словами, количество пикселей в физическом дюйме определить невозможно (PPI), поэтому предполагают, что дюйм - это просто 96 пикселей. Формула `DPI * N / 72` подходит лишь для шрифтов, т.к. N - высота в точках. Элементы UI рисуется не в точках, а в пикселях. Насколько мне известно, DWM сначала рисует окно такое, какое оно есть - размеры в пикселях, которые задумал разработчик. И уже после того, как окно нарисовано, берётся DPI системы и делится на 96 - получается коэффициент увеличения элементов UI.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю теперь, такое нелогичное действие, как деление DPI на 96, есть ничто иное как просто математическая операция. В ней нет смысла выразить что то в точках или в пикселях. Понятие DPI придумано в системе лишь для шрифтов.

Comment: Точка - единица независимая от устройства. Это 1/72 логического дюйма. Поэтому происходит увеличение шрифта. Чем больше DPI, тем больше пикселей занимает одна точка. Ситуация напоминает масштабирование в WPF, где используются независимые от устройства единицы.

Comment: Есть ли у вас почтовый адрес, по которому можно было бы обратиться к вам?

Comment: Я бы хотел проконсультироваться с вами по одному вопросу, который скорее всего не подходит к тематике SO))

Comment: Может быть я вам свой адрес дам, если вы не хотите оставлять здесь свой? Буду благодарен если поможете.